# How to find out the push time on git bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

We are using bitbucket and git repo. When I push stuff to bitbucket repo, I can see only the the time of the commit. Is there any way to find out when the commit was pushed to the remote repo?

In eclipse I can see the commit time like this:

```
commit 81109Epsdfogf76c5066836521f54c87
Author: Oli Müller  2023-08-11 18:00:27
Committer: Oli Müller  2023-08-11 18:00:27
```

Comment: Now, how automated you want this? One way would be if you are using pipelines is to see the pipeline start timers which usually start on push. Then you just compare the pipeline run starting points to figure out what commits were added between the pipeline runs. Manually that would mean looking at pipeline runs for the branch that included your wanted commit and checking pipeline run points and comparing it to git history.

Comment: Programatically is a whole different case, but here is an idea. On a commit you can see it's pipeline run status. If it doesn't have one you need to get the commit after, repeat till you find one, and then you get the start time for that pipeline run. I believe that commits pipeline runs are under status `statuses`, but there might be multiple so select the earliest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git itself doesn't track details of pushes, pulls, clones, or other activity which could go over a network. Instead, it leaves that to the respective protocol (HTTP, HTTPS, SSH, etc.) and focuses on commits themselves.

If you need push times instead of commit times, then you'll have to rely on your provider to expose those. If they don't, then you might be able to set up a webhook that notifies someplace else whenever there's a push; the details of webhooks on Bitbucket will vary between the cloud version (bitbucket.org, see https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/manage-webhooks/) and specific Server/Datacenter versions (https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/manage-webhooks-938025878.html is for 8.12 but you need to choose the correct version!).